# How can I install libmemcached on Openshift with sasl support?

Tags: python, django, sasl, openshift-online-2

I need libmemcached with sasl support to use Memcached Cloud cartridge on Openshift Online. I doing next:

1) Install sasl.

```
curl -LO ftp://ftp.cyrusimap.org/cyrus-sasl/cyrus-sasl-2.1.26.tar.gz
tar --xvzf cyrus-sasl-2.1.26.tar.gz
cd cyrus-sasl-2.1.26
sh configure --prefix=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}sasl
make
make install
```

2) Set up env variables(**Update:** added "&& export SASL_PATH"):

```
SASL_PATH = ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}sasl/lib/sasl2 && export SASL_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}sasl/lib/sasl2/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

3) Install libmemcached

```
curl -L -O https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.18/+download/libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
tar -xvzf libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-1.0.18
sh configure --prefix=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}libmemcached --enable-sasl
```

The result of configuring show me that:

> sasl support: no

But when I am installing on my local machine everything is good.

Maybe I should pass path to sasl, but how to do this?

Please help me.

Comment: wouldn't it help to `export SASL_PATH`

Comment: @Jakuje, I exported SASL_PATH, but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

In **step 3** you need to add the 2 variables with the correct path:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I${YOUR_DIR}/libs/include LDFLAGS=-L${YOUR_DIR}/libs/lib sh configure --prefix=${ROOT_DIR}/libs/ --enable-sasl
```

It worked for me on openshift.